# Django if table in template is empty display something else

Tags: django, templates

i would like to know how i can display a message like "Currently no Data Available" if the table is empty

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr style="font-size: small">
            <th>Ranking</th>
            <th>Symbol</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Market Cap (USD)</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for price in price %}
        <tr style="font-size: small">
            <td>{{ price.rank }}</td>
            <td>{{ price.symbol }}</td>
            <td>{{ price.key|title }}</td>
            <td>{{ price.value|intcomma }} $</td>
            <td>{{ price.market_cap_usd|intcomma }} $</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Thanks and Br

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django templates have a [**`for ... empty`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for-empty) pattern for this. You can write `{% for var in collection %} ... {% empty %} ... {% endfor %}`. In case the collection is not empty, then it will perform iteration and for each item in the collection render the body. In case the collection is empty it will render the bart between `{% empty %}` and `{% endfor %}`.

For example:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr style="font-size: small">
            <th>Ranking</th>
            <th>Symbol</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Market Cap (USD)</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for price in price %}
        <tr style="font-size: small">
            <td>{{ price.rank }}</td>
            <td>{{ price.symbol }}</td>
            <td>{{ price.key|title }}</td>
            <td>{{ price.value|intcomma }} $</td>
            <td>{{ price.market_cap_usd|intcomma }} $</td>
        </tr>
    {% empty %}
        <tr><td colspan="5">Currently no Data Available</td></tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In case the collection is empty, then the `{% empty %}` part is rendered.

> **Note**: please rename your collection to `prices`, so `{% for price in prices %}`, now you overwrite your template variable, and furthermore `prices` is more clear about what it contains.

Comment: Well that was simple. Best regards from a Pytohn newcomer ^^